# Android resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, studio, constraint-layout

Tengo unos problemas a la hora de ejecutar mi APP

Al darle al debug, sale todo correcto, *aparentemente*, pero en **Build output** sale lo siguiente, redirigiéndome a un XML que ni sé donde está.

Este es el error:

> C:\Users\mikel.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\001d91ef45f3598baad623d0ad4f091e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:268:5-4347: AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka code.ballahapps.tictactoe:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found
>
> C:\Users\mikel.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\001d91ef45f3598baad623d0ad4f091e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:269:5-3548: AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka code.ballahapps.tictactoe:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found

¿Podría alguien arrojarme un poco de luz?

Son 16 errores y en los 16 pone lo mismo, cambia algún número antes del AAPT y ya.

Tengo el *Build Gradle* y demás actualizado a las últimas versiones (6.5 y 4.1.0).

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Te dice que el recurso no existe , de donde viste o sacaste este attr/flow_horizontalSeparator ?  y en donde lo estas poniendo?

Comment: Perdón no vi tu comentario , es una app de codecanyon

Comment: Estas actualizando tu app a Android X?? o es un desarrollo totalmente nuevo

Comment: Revisa [este hilo en github](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/issues/37) para ver si te ayuda en algo

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos ahora creo que lo tengo solucionado siguiendo los pasos que me escribisteis de Android X , mil gracias 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes asegurar usar la versión 2.0.0 o mayor para `ConstraintLayout` :

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
```

y asegurar usar `AndroidX`, te sugiero revisar que en tu proyecto o bibliotecas se use:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualizo para comentaros que por fin di con la solución , por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro :

Lo que hice fue, actualizar el constraintLayout

Lo tenía en 2.0.0-beta2 (si mal no recuerdo)

Lo actualicé a 2.0.0-beta4 y pude solucionar todos los problemas

Agradezco a todos vosotros vuestro tiempo y las respuestas ya que me habéis ayudado